# Collect product variable and find the largest one in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing some code to supply the Google certified shop data which I have nearly finished. I only need to supply the ship and delivery dates.  I have written code to supply this information at the product level.  However when there is more than one product in an order I need to select the largest ship date.

For example;
Order has two products.
Producta with $ship_date = 2  and porductb with $ship_date = 5

I need to collect all the $ship_dates (2 and 5) and return the highest one (5).
My question is simply how do I write the php to collect all the $ship_dates correctly - should I create an array and if so how?

Comment: As long as you don't provide code you won't get an useful answer. However, based on what you described, read more about the PHP functions [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

Comment: Its more about an approach than specific syntax.  I am getting a whole list of product information in a loop;
$line_items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $line_items as $item )  {
$product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
$prod_name = $item['name'];

Comment: If you already have a loop over the list then you can compute the max  in the loop and also remember the item that reaches the max.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the required variables into an array, then use [`max`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

```
$ship_date1 = 2;
$ship_date2 = 5;
$shipDates = [$ship_date1, $ship_date2];
// other dates as needed

// OR, a much cleaner solution, append to the array
$shipDates = [];
$shipDates[] = 2;
$shipDates[] = 5;

//No matter how you fill up the array, this is how you get its maximum value
$maxShipDate = max($shipDates);
```

`max` actually accepts individual variables instead (eg. `max($ship_date1, $ship_date2);`) but the array solution is easier to maintain.

Comment: I don't know how many ship dates there will be in each order so I need a way to automatically collect from 1 to an unlimited number of ship dates.  Secondly because the ship dates for each product are collected in a loop the variable for all of them is $ship_date.   I was thinking of something like
 foreach( $ship_date as $key => $value){
    $string = $value.',';
}
but I'm not sure that is right.

Answer (score 0):

OK before my foreach product loop I added this;
$deliverydatearray = array();
which creates a new (empty) array which I called $deliverydatearray

Within my foreach product loop I added this;
$deliverydatearray[] = $delivery_datep;
which adds my product specific delivery date ($delivery_datep) to my array.

After the foreach product loop has closed I can access the variables in my array.  For example just printing the contents of the array is done like this;
    print_r($deliverydatearray);
which looks like this;
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-01-28
    [1] => 2017-01-23
)